# UpdateOne mongodb without changing others objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Let see the example below

[image: MongoDB Schema]

I want to update just one record inside my ExpensesHouse so I build the following code

```
router.post("/editExpense/:id", ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);
  House.updateOne(
    { "expensesHouse._id": id },
    {
      $set: {
        expensesHouse: {
          _id: id,
          expenseType: req.body.expenseType,
          description: req.body.description,
          price: req.body.price,
          status: req.body.status,
          userID: req.user.id
        }
      }
    }
  ).then(house => {
    req.flash("success_msg", "Expenses Updated");
    res.redirect("/houses/dashboard");
  });
});
```

It works fine and can update the record, but since I have 2 or more Objects all the others gone. 
So when I update let suppose 1: Object, expenseType: Water and I change the type of expense to other, the 0: Object just disappear and I need to update only the register with the _id: id

Below you can see the result after UpdateOne

[image: MongoDB Afeer Update]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
router.post("/editExpense/:houseId/:id", ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);
  var houseId : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.houseId);
  House.updateOne(
    { "_id": houseID, "expensesHouse._id": id },
    {
      $set: {
          expensesHouse.$.expenseType: req.body.expenseType,
          expensesHouse.$.description: req.body.description,
          expensesHouse.$.price: req.body.price,
          expensesHouse.$.status: req.body.status,
          expensesHouse.$.userID: req.user.id
        }
      }
    }
  ).then(house => {
    req.flash("success_msg", "Expenses Updated");
    res.redirect("/houses/dashboard");
  });
});
```

Comment: Didn't work this way. How do you use a houseID if I don't have any houseID ?

Comment: The first id on document aren't the house id?

Comment: Yes but this ID should match in this condition ( "expensesHouse._id": id ) and it match.

Comment: I just sit and think about your solution and I change some things there and it worked.
I will update the question and show the problem solved. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The houseId should be part of query to improve the performance. So, if you pass just the expensesHouseId, the database will search on all documents in database. But, if you add the houseId parameter, this would be much more fast and consumes less memory and processor.